# Connecting to Redis instance from Google cloud function is failing

Tags: node.js, function, google-cloud-platform, redis, connection

I am trying to connect to the Google cloud redis instance from Google cloud function, i am using the same code provided in GCP platform,

```
***'use strict';
 const http = require('http');
 const redis = require('redis');
 const REDISHOST = process.env.REDISHOST || 'localhost';
 const REDISPORT = process.env.REDISPORT || 6379;
 const client = redis.createClient(REDISPORT, REDISHOST);
 client.on('error', err => console.error('ERR:REDIS:', err));***
```

However, that code is not working. After going through various articles I found that we need to use a URL as shown below

```
***const redisURL = "redis://foo.bar.org:6379"
 redis.createClient( {url: redisURL} )***
```

My question is, where can I get the URL details in GCP in order to use it in the code.

Comment: Savitha, did I answer your question? If so, please accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Using `gcloud`, run the following command:

```
gcloud redis instances describe REDIS-INSTANCE --region=REGION --project=PROJECT
```

`REDIS-INSTANCE` is the name you gave your redis instance when you created it.

If successful, gcloud returns details about the instance, including:

```
.
host: 10.0.0.27
.
port: 6379
.
```

=> `redis://10.0.0.27:6379`

See:
https://cloud.google.com/memorystore/docs/redis/create-instance-gcloud#creating-redis